# Creating a flexible temporary game data storage system

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, arraylist

I'm making a 2D physics game with Java and have recently decided to completely start over so that the program's foundations have flexibility and threading in mind since. My problem is finding a way to store my game data for the duration of the program with threading in mind.

My previous library for storing data looked like this

```
public float[] sphereX = new float[sphereNum];
public float[] sphereY = new float[sphereNum];
public float[] sphereXMem = new float[sphereNum];
public float[] sphereYMem = new float[sphereNum];
public float[] sphereVX = new float[sphereNum]; // X Velocity
public float[] sphereVY = new float[sphereNum]; // Y Velocity

// Misc Variables
public float[] sphereMass = new float[sphereNum];
public float[] sphereRadius = new float[sphereNum];
```

While this was good for a program without threading and fewer features, my current program will have several new requirements that this previous version did not address. These include:

- The amount of spheres is constantly changing
- Spheres have even more data types. (boolean, int, and float)
- This game data is being continually accessed and modified by multiple threads

I worry that locking threads out of data until the lock key becomes available will slow the program down significantly since about 1-4 threads will be chugging away at calculating all the physics.

My current idea of a solution is to have an Arraylist of objects that containing an array of that object's parameters, but I do not have a clue as to how to make that work with threading.

As you might guess, I'm somewhat new with threading but know basic concepts of volatility and basic synchronization. Also, if you wanted to know, I'm using threading to hopefully allow my program to take advantage of multiple cores.

Edit: After consideration from the comments I've come up with this. Is this right? I didn't intend to create a separate class at the start, but it is probably for the best. I feel stupid asking this, but will it retain its information if I place all of it in a separate file? From this, I'd just add multiple Items (Item is the new Sphere) to my ArrayList in the main class?

```
enter code here`public class Item 
{
    private Object lockActive = new Object();
    private Object lockType = new Object();
    private Object lockMass = new Object();
    private Object lockLocation = new Object();
    private Object lockLocationMemory = new Object();
    private Object lockVelocity = new Object();

    private boolean active;
    private int type;
    private float mass;
    private float[] location;
    private float[] locationMemory;
    private float[] velocity;

    public Item(boolean active, int type, float mass, float[] location, float[] locationMemory, float[] velocity) 
    {
        this.active = active;
        this.type = type;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.location = location;
        this.locationMemory = locationMemory;
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public boolean GetActive() 
    {
        synchronized (lockActive)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return active;
        }
    }

    public synchronized int GetType() 
    {
        synchronized (lockType)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return type;
        }
    }

    public synchronized float GetMass() 
    {
        synchronized (lockMass)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mass;
        }
    }

    public synchronized float[] GetLocation() 
    {
        synchronized (lockLocation)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return location;
        }
    }

    public synchronized float[] GetLocationMemory() 
    {
        synchronized (lockLocationMemory)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return locationMemory;
        }
    }

    public synchronized float[] GetVelocity() 
    {
        synchronized (lockVelocity)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return velocity;
        }
    }

    public void SetActive() 
    {
        synchronized (lockActive)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.active = active;
        }
    }

    public void SetType(int type) 
    {
        synchronized (lockType)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public void SetMass(float mass) 
    {
        synchronized (lockMass)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.mass = mass;
        }
    }

    public void SetLocation(float[] location) 
    {
        synchronized (lockLocation)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.location = location;
        }
    }

    public void SetLocationMemory(float[] locationMemory) 
    {
        synchronized (lockLocationMemory)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.locationMemory = locationMemory;
        }
    }

    public void SetVelocity(float[] velocity) 
    {
        synchronized (lockVelocity)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.velocity = velocity;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that to yourself.  Rather than making one data-structure per attribute, define a sphere object to hold all of a sphere's attributes.  Write synchronized methods so that multiple threads don't alter a single sphere at once.

Here's a quick and dirty start:

```
//Sphere.java
public class Sphere {
    private float[] position;
    private float[] mem; 
    private float[] velocity;

    public Sphere(float[] position, float[] mem,  float[] velocity) {
        this.position = position;
        this.mem = mem;
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public synchronized float[] getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public synchronized float[] getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public synchronized void move() {
        position[0]+=velocity[0];
        position[1]+=velocity[1];
    }
}
```

Then you might initialize your data somewhere else:

```
    int sphereCount = 30;
    List<Sphere> spheres = new ArrayList<Sphere>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for( int i = 0; i < sphereCount; i++) {
        spheres.add(
            new Sphere(
                new float[]{20*rand.nextFloat(), 20*rand.nextFloat()}, //position
                new float[]{20*rand.nextFloat(), 20*rand.nextFloat()}, //mem
                new float[]{2*rand.nextFloat(), 2*rand.nextFloat()} //velocity
            )
        );
    }
```

Again, this is just rough, vague code, and I haven't given it much thought.  The big idea here is to use objects to describe 'things' so that you can put all the nitty-gritty code to manipulate them in those objects and out of the rest of your code.

As for the `synchronized` keyword, it means that everything within that method happens either completely before or completely after any other synchronized method call on that same object.

Comment: I did want to get away from doing what I showed above, but I'm not entirely sure on how to do what you are saying.

Comment: further improvements might be using a `Position` and a `Velocity` class. Making those objects immutable. Utilizing `volatile` and eliminating `synchronized`.

Comment: Okay, I follow now with that edit. That technique looks like it may work. I still feel a little confused, but maybe that's because I need to step away from this for a bit. Edit: Tim Bender, thanks for that suggestion.